# jQuery load wont fire callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, load, fadein

I have this function:

```
$("#menuwrap").fadeOut(300, function () {
$("#menuwrap").load(url, function () {
    $("#menuwrap").fadeIn(300);
});
});
```

But the callback action for `.load()` wont fire. `#menuwrap` is stuck with an inline `style="display:none"`.

Even an `alert()` before the `fadeIn()` won't show.

Never had this trouble before. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `load()` work without the `fadeOut()`, i.e. stand-alone?

Comment: Does the content you're loading also have an `id="menuwrap"` by chance?

Comment: @NobRuked: Yes, it works. The contents in `#menuwrap` do change, even with the snippet I posted.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I double checked, but there's only one `id="menuwrap` in the resulting markup. No duplications, not even within the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a script in the resulting HTML being loaded (AKA'url' var).

The script in said document was buggy, and therefore all further scripts (such as `$("#menuwrap").fadeIn(300)`) where not executed.

So, hide yo' wives, hide yo' daughters, double-check your asyncroncally loaded scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7etkY/7/). Try to check your URL for `load()` and it's content.

Comment: The URL is fine. It loads, and the HTML content of `#menuwrap` does change. I can tell by looking into Chromes DOM Inspector.